# textfile with textdat containg cell of chars

Tags: matlab

Please consinder this output:

```matlab
filecontent.textdata(:,idx.u_0)

ans =
  297×1 cell array
    {'"u[m/s]"'}

    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'0'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'5'       }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
    {'10'      }
```

is there a way to treat this as numeric? i want o compared  with a vector[0:5:50] and get the index and finally sort the entire data row wise .
thanks

Comment: `str2double`, `cell2mat`, ... What have you tried and why isn't it working? What do you mean by "treat as numeric"? What's your expected output?

Comment: thanks very  much  i wanted to numeric not cell of  chars. however i got the solution already. thank you for your time .

Comment: To close the question, please add the solution you found or delete the question if it was trivial...

Answer (score 0):

I simply drag and drop the file in  Matlab work space and  generate a script  which convert the entire file to numeric